# get the color value from <p id="Text_Font" runat="server" style="color:#FFDDAA"> in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have this in my HTML

```
<p id="Text_Font" runat="server" style="color:#FFDDAA"> Hallo word</p>
```

so how do i get the value of the color from the style in my asp.net
not the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the controls `Style` property and get the value but this would work if it's a server side control (with `runat="server"`)

```
string color = this.Text_Font.Style["color"];
```